# Blazor on Azure Linux App Services failing

Tags: azure-web-app-service, blazor-webassembly

I am using Azure DevOps to deploy my Blazor WASM to a Linux Web App in Azure AppService.
The deployments succeeded, but the website is not showing the deployed content. I used the same pipeline to deploy to a Windows Web App in App Service and it worked. Is there any issues with Blazor WASM and Azure App Service (Linux). I Ensured that I selected the correct .NET Stack in both Web Apps.

```
azor
dependsOn: Build_Blazor_App
condition: and(eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'Manual'), eq('${{parameters.DeployBlazor}}', true) ) # We need deployment to happen only for manual one.
jobs:
  - job: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy To Azure
    steps:
      - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
        displayName: Downloading Artifacts
        inputs:
          buildType: 'current'
          artifactName: 'blaze'
          targetPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)'
      
      - task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
        displayName: Deploying to Dev
        inputs:
          ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
          azureSubscription: 'Az_VS_Enterprise'
          appType: 'webAppLinux'
          WebAppName: 'smartlytics'
          packageForLinux: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/Smarter.Blazor.zip'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any issues with Blazor WASM and Azure App Service (Linux).

Followed by  [***Microsoft Documentation***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/webassembly?view=aspnetcore-6.0#azure-app-service) :

> Currently ,To deploy a Standalone Blazor WebAssembly app to Azure app
> service on Linux ***is not supported***. A Linux server image to host
> the app isn't available at this moment.
>
> We can deploy Blazor WebAssembly apps to Azure App Services on
> Windows, which host the apps on IIS .